# How to set "python" as default

Tags: python, linux, terminal, line, default

Hello can someone help me with this.
So the issue is that I started using linux and I need to make my "python3" line code into just "python". For example -- "python3 run.py" (this is now), but i want just
"python run.py". If someone can help me it would made my day

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3

Comment: ! If Debian, Ubuntu, Mint : Changing anything with the system python can make apt / dpkg unusable .... see the previous comment, @Trevor Pogue.

Comment: For your personal preference, a shell alias or function may be the easiest. If you need to switch between Python versions, maybe look into `pyenv`. Going forward, please search before asking.

Comment: "Linux" is a very broad target anyway. Different distros have different policies, different packaging regimes, and different conventions. You have received several answers which presuppose a Debian-based distribution, which are useless on non-Debian distros (RPM, Alpine, Arch, Slack, Gentoo, etc). Probably [edit] to specify in more detail which system you're on (but this will then probably be a duplicate of an existing question anyway) or if you're only looking for a personal configuration (in which case which shell etc).

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75384136/update-gcc-on-ubuntu/75384479#75384479) question asks a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

All these answers assume your system doesn't have Python 2 installed, otherwise you might cause other issues.

The recommended way if you are using BASH on Linux or UNIX, is to edit the .bashrc file in your home directory :

> ~/.bashrc

The '~' 'points to your home directory '/home/username'. Once you have this file open, add the following to the bottom :

> alias python='python3'

Now typing 'python' will automatically run Python 3. I use this method because it doesn't require altering system files, but you can't run as sudo (which might be a good thing).

If you need to use 'sudo', create a symbolic link with the following command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

Alternatively install the 'python-is-python3' package, as mentioned by @chepner the following assumes you are using the apt package manager, and similarly does nothing more than create a symbolic link :

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

Comment: The `apt` solution is highly dependent on you using `apt` as a package manager and your repository supplying the `python-is-python3` package. It's not generally applicable to all Linux installations.

Comment: You shouldn't manually create symlinks under `/usr/bin`; that's reserved for whatever is responsible for installing and maintaining your OS installation.

Comment: Upvoting for the alias suggestion, though. (It's not my personal preference, but it's perfectly fine.)

Comment: The correct place for any local system overrides is `/usr/local/bin`, not `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Thank you @chepner, agree with everything you said.

Comment: @tripleee completely correct, thank you.  I have changed the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to terminal type - python --version
2.Log in with root privileges   sudo su
3.Execute this command   update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3
4. Check version again

Comment: This assumes a system that provides the `update-alternatives` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can install python-is-python3 package:
`$ sudo apt install python-is-python3`

Comment: If you use `apt` and your default repositories supply `python-is-python3`.