# Update GCC on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc, ubuntu-20.04

I am on a project that needs GCC 10.x or later.

At this time I have GCC 9.4.0 on Ubuntu 20.04.1. I tried to update the compiler, but it does not work.

Can anybody give me an advice for the update?

I read on the gcc website that version 9.4 is more up-to-date than some 10.x versions. How is Gcc structured?

among other things I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-10.2 g++-10.2
```

but after all my gcc version is still 9.4

```
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
```

Comment: GCC 10 will be named `gcc-10` (or something similar, not `gcc`). *"version 9.4 is more up-to-date than some 10.x versions"* They mean 9.y can be released after 10.x to fix some bugs in the old version, but it doesn't really matter. Bigger number = better version.

Comment: You could also upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 which is the latest LTS version and it comes with gcc 11.3. I did that on my Ubuntu WSL installation and it was a painless upgrade.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/26498/how-to-choose-the-default-gcc-and-g-version

Answer (score 10):

This is a common pattern in linux. When there are multiple versions of the same program installed, though the executables are all present in the `/usr/bin/` directory, only one of them is "visible" as that program. For example, if you install `gcc-9` and `gcc-10`, both executables are present as `/usr/bin/gcc-9` and `/usr/bin/gcc-10` but only one of them is visible as `gcc`. This happens by [symlinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) a preferred version to the same directory as `/usr/bin/gcc`. In ubuntu 20.04, the preferred version is `gcc-9` and so, `gcc-9` is symlinked as `gcc`.

You can check this by running the following command.

```
$ which gcc | xargs file
```

The output will be

```
/usr/bin/gcc: symbolic link to gcc-9
```

There are a few things you can do to use `gcc-10` as your c compiler.

1. Directly call the `gcc-10` executable. Instead of using `gcc <code.c>`, call `gcc-10 <code.c>`.
2. You can manually symlink `gcc-10` as the preferred `gcc`. Assuming you did not modify the system paths, the following command can be used.

```
# ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-10 /usr/local/bin/gcc
```

This works because, by default, the executables in `/usr/local/bin/` take precedence over `/usr/bin/`.

3. If you are using bash, you can create an alias for `gcc` as `gcc-10`. Add the following line to your `.bashrc`.

```
alias gcc="gcc-10"
```

Remember to relaunch bash or `source ~/.bashrc`.

4. Using `update-alternatives` (Thanks to @ted-lyngmo for pointing it out). Debian based distributions supply a separate program, that can make symlinking easier / more functional. Read more using `man update-alternatives`. To use `gcc-10` as the preferred `gcc`, use the following command.

```
# update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-10 60
```

The above command says, `/usr/bin/gcc` is the `link` needed and the `name` is `gcc`, the target executable is `/usr/bin/gcc-10` and it has a priority of 60.

This links `gcc` to `/etc/alternatives/gcc`, which itself is a symlink to `/usr/bin/gcc-10`. If a higher priority program is added to `update-alternatives`, `/etc/alternatives/gcc` points to the higher priority program.

If you don't have any specific reason, I would also recommend to upgrade to a newer ubuntu version, so that the default `gcc` is a newer one.

> I read on the gcc website that version 9.4 is more up-to-date than some 10.x versions.

With newer `gcc` versions, new features are added. Support for newer c/c++ standards are also added. Eg. You can read the changes for `gcc-10` [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/changes.html). But people still need `gcc-9` because some programs only build with `gcc-9`. So, GNU maintains `gcc-9` (and much older versions) for a long time. Bugs are fixed, and newer releases are made. This can happen after the release of a newer `gcc` version. So, it is very much possible that a version of `gcc-9` is newer than a version of `gcc-10`.

Comment: Instead of manually linking, use `alternatives`. `man update-alternatives`: _"maintain symbolic links determining default commands"_